# How to deserialize theefold nested json data?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

Consuming a RestAPI I get a Json file that holds data of surveys. I load the file into the following class:

```
Public Class GeneralInfo
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property data As List(Of FullData)
End Class
```

Every survey has an id, a name and data.

```
Public Class FullData
    Public Property userID As ULong
    Public Property data As List(Of String)
End Class
```

Every survey holds data for each participant. I use Newtonsoft.Json to get the data into my classes.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of GeneralInfo))(jstr)
```

The data within the data-property is comma separated but the length is different for every survey. So in survey 1 can be 100 datapoints (one for each answer to a question) and in survey 2 can be up to 400 datapoints. A few of these datapoints can include comma as well since there are datapoints that hold open questions.

I just do not know how to store these data properly. I already read into the JsonConvert and could accomplish getting the data into the classes you can see above but here it ends. Could anyone help me out here? I address these to c# as well since I do not care if the solution is c# or vb.net.

Here are some sample data:

```
[{"id":1,
    "name":"2015 - companyname.dpt",
    "data":[{
        "userId":364,
        "data":["367","90","company","","","Anonymous","User","anonymous@provider.org","","100.100.100.100","14242","undefined","0","7891","2","2","3","1","","","","","","","2015","1","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","3","3","2","1","3","3","3","4","3","3","4","2","3","3","2","3","2","3","4","3","","4","5","3","4","2","4","4","4","4","4","2","4","4","2","2","4","3","4","4","4","4","3","","1","1","1","5","1","1","1","","1","1","1","1","1","3","3","3","3","4","4","1","","","","2","2","3","1","","","","","","","","",""]
    }, {"userID": 365, ...}]
}]
```

Comment: Sample data or a link to some would be nice.  The `List` ought  to be able to store the answer elements, but it might depend on how they are stored; it could be some other Type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just added some sample data.

Comment: I changed/fixed the second record to `{"userId": 365,  "data":["367","90","foo,bar"]}` and deserialized it and it worked fine.  The first has 121 elements, the second has 3.  Whats the problem you are having?

Comment: The fulldata, data property delivers a list of string and I thought there might be a chance to get these information also as property values like data.property1 = 367, data.property2 = 90 ...

Comment: Well, you are being passed a `List<String>` so, its just `jData(0).data(0).data(7)` (your names, not mine) which is: `"anonymous@provider.org"`  there are no property names/references supplied for the elements.

Comment: ah, great. I will go that way and query the object as you suggest. thanks for your help!